# База данных Python в облаке

Tags: python, база-данных, облако

Есть задача создать визуальное редактирование(запись, удаление, просмотр) базы данных с помощью программы написанной на Python(десктоп). Возможно ли работать с базой данных в облаке(через интернет)? И как это будет происходить?
Благодарю заранее за ответ и уделенное время.

Comment: Возможно. Можете цепляться DB-API напрямую на порт СУБД, но лучше набросать простой CRUD-сервис и общаться с базой через него REST-запросами.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо написать серверное API которое будет возвращать ответы от REST запросов в удобном для тебя формате, и ещё тебе обязательно нужна база данных на сервере. REST запросы соответственно отправляешь из своего декстопного приложения

В качестве инструмента для серверного API советую использовать Flask [Документация](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

База данных например - Postgresql, хотя можешь использовать любую удобную для тебя